# Can I include persistence.xml file in my own .jar file?

Tags: java

Can we include persistence.xml file in our own user define .jar file in jpa. If yes, then please guide me how can we add the persistence.xml file in folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, persistence.xml goes in

```
META-INF/persistence.xml
```

if you are packaging it inside a *.jar, or

```
WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

if you are packaging it inside a *.war

Comment: thank you, but i've added persistence.xml in my own *.jar file, if i open persistence.xml after including into another project it is saying "An error has occurred. See error log for more details. java.lang.NullPointerException". please can you say what is the problem.